# How can I solve the error I'm still getting from my embedded youtube video?

Tags: html, youtube, playback

I'm trying to embed a youtube video into one of my certification projects and I made sure to add the "embed" within the url but I'm still getting an error

```
<iframe id="video" width="444" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gYvoD2RZK1A&t=164s&ab_channel=BLOCKHEAD">Video not available...</iframe>
```

Open to any input thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The embed is not working because the first GET is a `&` and not a `?` in the source link. [Read more about HTTP Method GET](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Here is the embed code for your video at the starting point 2:44.

```
<iframe id="video" width="444" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gYvoD2RZK1A?start=164" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If you click the share button under youtube videos and then embed, youtube generates the embed code you need!

Answer (score 0):

Just take away the excess

```
<iframe id="video" width="444" height="281" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gYvoD2RZK1A"></iframe>
```